# Solr date range filtering

Tags: solr

Looking at the [docs](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/working-with-dates.html#WorkingwithDates-DateRangeFormatting),

> [2000-11-01 TO 2014-12-01] – The specified date range at a day resolution.

When I tried that, I got `Invalid Date String` error.

After looking at other answers, I found that I need to specify in `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ` format.

This works for me - `[2000-11-01T00:00:00Z TO 2014-12-01T23:59:59Z]`

---

So adding `T00:00:00Z` in the start_date  and `T23:59:59Z`in the end_date is the only option?

---

EDIT: Field type is `TrieDateField`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs you're linking is explicitly for the `DateRangeField`. If your field is one of the two other formats, `TrieDateField` or `DatePointField` depending on which version of Solr you're using, you have to use the complete, full format. It's a field implementation detail.